# How to generate java classes from a formal asn1 classes definition?

Tags: java, asn.1

I have a formal asn1 classes definition for some custom domain.

What would be the most straightforward way to generate the corresponding set of java classes together with a reader/writer so I can read those classes from an `InputStream` and write to an `OutputStream`?

I'm looking into Bouncy Castle library if that counts as a minimal necessary research. I think I might be able to get a quicker answer here though. Never done this before.

Answer (score 1):

You need an ASN.1 Compiler that takes the spec and generates Java classes (usually associated to a runtime encoder/decoder)

Some pointers. I cannot give advice on any of them, since I never used ASN.1 with Java.... just the first hits from Google.

- [ITU-T ASN.1 Tools page](http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx). Have whole section on Java tools...
- [ASN Lab](http://www.asnlab.com/asnjc/overview.html)
- [JAC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jac-asn1/)